# How do you demonstrate that a hexagon is a regular hexagon?

Tags: geometry, soft-question

How do you demonstrate that a hexagon is a regular hexagon?

I think that showing that all the sides are congruent isn't enough. What are the crietria we can use to show that a hexagon is regular? Hope one of you can help! Thank you!

Comment: How is the hexagon given?

Comment: A regular hexagon is both equilateral (all sides are congruent) and equiangular (all interior angles are congruent, and since the sum of interior angles in a polygon is $(n-2) \times 180^\circ$, 120$^\circ$ in an equiangular hexagon).